# NIS and autofs error

Tags: rhel, nfs, nis, autofs

I am trying to share the home directory of a NIS user using NFS and autofs. During testing, I get the following error message:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/guest/nis1: Permission denied
-bash: /home/guest/nis1/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

How can I troubleshoot the above error?

Comment: The first thing to look at is `ls -l /home/guest/nis1`. Are you sure that the NFS server, the NIS server and the client all have the same user ID for `nis1`?

Comment: Hi Gilles ,

How can I check this ???

Jack

Comment: @user2914: See [loopforever's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4547/4571#4571). Are the NFS server and the NIS server the same machine? If you have shell access to it, what does `getent passwd nis1` show there? Does it work if you mount the home directory manually?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getent passwd nis1` (where `nis1` is the user in your example) to get the passwd entry the NFS client is seeing for 'nis1'. getent respects `nsswitch.conf`, which supplies ordering for nameservice lookups across multiple services (files, nis, ldap, etc...).

After you determine the UID in that response, compare it to the UID who owns the home directory, `/home/guest/nis1` by running: `stat /home/guest/nis1`.

Your problem may be that the permissions on the home directory are restrictive such that there is no execute bit for other (o+x) and the UID that owns the directory is not actually the UID that the NFS client can resolve for that username.

It would be helpful if you provided the output of these commands, even if this answer is not correct so that we can continue to troubleshoot.

Comment: #stat /home/guest/nis1                                                                                                                                    Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  503/     nis1)   Gid: (  504/     nis1)
Access: 2010-12-06 16:35:37.000000000 +0545
Modify: 2010-12-04 14:50:00.000000000 +0545
Change: 2010-12-04 15:50:27.000000000 +0545

Comment: [root@station2 pest]# getent passwd nis1
nis1:$1$fUdoS4mo$gUwfCjH5jJT5cc9prleKv.:503:504::/home/guest/nis1:/bin/bash

Comment: # mount -t nfs NFS_and_NIS_server:/home/guest/nis1 /home/guest/nis1                       --even after this, I got the same error....