# Problem with NIS

Tags: administration, nis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NIS and autofs error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4547/nis-and-autofs-error)

I have one server and one client machine.

In Server, I have configured NIS, and /home/guest/nis1 is shared through NFS. Both NFS and NIS are configured in same server.

In client, I have configured autofs to export home directory of NIS user. When I try to login in client from nis1 username then I got the following error message.

Could not chdir to home directory /home/guest/nis1: Permission denied
-bash: /home/guest/nis1/.bash_profile: Permission denied
-bash-3.1$

How Can i troubleshot??

Comment: This is exactly the same situation as [NIS and autofs error](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4547/nis-and-autofs-error), down to the example user name. Do you have a problem with account association, is this homework, are you both following the same tutorial, or what?